# Xcode 14.2 Rejected My iOS App with Deployment Target iOS 15.0. How to fix ITMS-90338: Non-public API Usage Error?

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store-connect

**App Rejected - Xcode 14.2 with deployment target iOS 15.0**

With Xcode 14.2 now I need to use deployment target as iOS 12 otherwise app is getting rejected after submitting the binary.Previous release 2/3 weeks before deployed with iOS 14.4 on Xcode 13.x.x was fine.

Message from Apple
Dear Developer,
We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "App Name" Version.
Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
**ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage** - The app contains one or more corrupted binaries. Rebuild the app and resubmit.. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/
Best regards,
The App Store Team

Comment: I suppose they are telling you which private API you are using, so don’t use it. If you wrote a function that has by coincidence the same name as a private function then rename it.